# How do I set read/write permissions my hard drives?

Tags: permissions

I've recently installed Ubuntu 11.10 on my laptop, but I can't do anything with my 1.5TB external drive, and my 500GB because I don't have write permission. Are there any specific commands I can use in the terminal to set the read/write permissions?

The external is NTFS, and the 500GB is ext4.

Comment: your external hard drive has which file system ? ext4 , ntfs ?

Comment: if it is a ntfs drive then this Q&A should work:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/14863/how-to-auto-mount-a-flash-drive-with-root-and-read-write-execute-privileges

Comment: The external is NTFS, and the 500GB is ext4.

Answer (score 56):

for your 500 GB hard-drive (ext4) filesystem, you need to give the write and execute permission on `/media/username/your_drive` partition:-

```
sudo chmod ugo+wx /media/username/your_drive
```

**Brief Explanation:**-

**sudo** :- it will elevate your priviledges to execute the command.

**chmod**:- command to change the permissions

**u** :- user

**g**:- group

**o** :- other

**/media/username/your_drive** :- partition

For your NTFS partition please follow [fossfreedom's advice.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90339/how-do-i-set-read-write-permissions-my-hard-drives#comment103281_90339)

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: It might be a good idea to omit the `o`

Comment: This works, but cannot do `ls` inside that disk.

Comment: @loretoparisi try `sudo chmod ugo+rwx /media/username/your_drive` the `r` in the flags tells the computer to allow you to read as well as write and execute.

Comment: why this not work for me ? I need to do `sudo chown username:username /media/mountpoint`

Answer (score 27):

If you don't mind the security problems you can do a recursive chmod in order to change the permissions of all the files.

```
cd /media/your_external_drive
sudo chmod -R -v 777 *
```

Also if your files were created in another OS like windows they will have different ownership you can do the same as above to change the ownership of the files

```
cd /media/your_external_drive
sudo chown -R -v your_username:your_username *
```

Thats the way I solved a similar problem for my friend after migrating from windows and also after migrating from Linux Mint to Ubuntu.

Comment: I used this after formatting an old hard drive using GParted.

Comment: Don't mark all your files as executable. See [below](http://askubuntu.com/a/773284/236476).

Comment: To only give yourself permission for the drive, but not for all of its contents, use: `sudo chown -v your_username:your_username /media/your_external_drive`

Comment: **Please don't recommend `0777` a.k.a. “please-hack-my-system-and-destroy-my-data” permissions for no apparent reason!** There's almost never a reason to do that because it can be avoided with more sensible modifications like changing (group) ownership. −1

Answer (score 12):

To fix read/write issue ntfs, just install these packages:

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-config ntfs-3g
```

when installed, in the dash, type in and run: `ntfs-config` enter your password when prompted, and then you can enjoy read/write support for ntfs file systems.

Comment: this fixed my problem in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 6):

Don't mark all your files as executable as some answers suggest. Use `755` for directories and `644` for files. This will set the `x` bit for directories in order to list their contents but not for files.

```
find /path/to/drive \( -type d -exec chmod 0755 -- {} + \) -o \( -type f -exec chmod 0644 -- {} + \)
```

Link to the original answer on StackOverflow: [How to set chmod for a folder and all of its subfolders and files in Linux Ubuntu Terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11512211/1079110).

Comment: @DavidFoerster Hi, thanks for the edit. This seems like a rather big change. Maybe it should be another answer instead?

Comment: Tell you what: I'll meet you in the middle and change the `find` command so that it does *exactly* the same as your *two* `find` command but with only one pass through all directories.

Comment: Sure. You can also add the alternative below, I think it's a very practical command.

Answer (score 3):

I formatted my extended partition using GParted and the resulted drive had only root level access. In order to grant access to my username, I executed below command.

```
sudo chown -v username:username /media/username/disk-name
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and solved it with nautilus as root.

if nautilus is not installed:

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus
```

Before running nautilus make sure the partition or hard disk is mounted.

Run nautilus as root with

```
sudo nautilus
```

Your partition or hard disk should appear on the left.

Right click on it -> select "Properties"

In the new window that appears, select the "Permissions" tab. From here you can change the owner if you need to, as well as the permission for a certain user, root, or others.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Comment: I just keep getting `Error setting permissions: Read only file system.` if I try to change the permissions in Nautlius properties.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a hard time solving the problem and this solution worked for me

1. install physical storage device manger:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install pysdm
   ```
2. Open storage device manger:

   ```
   sudo pysdm
   ```
3. Choose your required drives
4. Press assist
5. Uncheck open as read only
6. Check owner user of file system and write your username
7. Press ok and apply
8. Remount the drive

Note: if you can't change files to binary executables, go to special files and check permit execution of files as binaries, and go to step 7

Comment: i installed `pysdm` before. Today, after a year or so i am trying to install pysdm again. I am getting `Unable to locate package pysdm`

Comment: Same here. It must not be available anymore.

Comment: `pysdm` was removed because it was buggy (https://askubuntu.com/questions/237066/where-is-the-pysdm-package).

Answer (score 1):

Using Terminal (Use this when you are currently logged in Ubuntu):

1. Quickly open the terminal or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>
2. First you need to find out the partition’s name which you want to access, run the following command:

   ```
   sudo fdisk -l
   ```
3. Then run this command in your terminal, to access your drive in read/write mode.

   ```
   mount -t ntfs-3g -o rw /dev/sda1 /media/<YOUR-Partition-name>
   ```

   OR
   Run this command (if the previous didn’t work)

   ```
   sudo ntfsfix /dev/<YOUR-Partition-name>
   ```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This looks like a copy-paste of [this web page](https://www.anudit.in/2015-09-10-can%27t-access-windows-files-in-ubuntu/). When providing answers, please provide them in your own words. Also, please provide attribution to the sources you used.

Answer (score 0):

I look around the forum for answers.

I have 3 users, "user1" ,"user2", "user3":

- user1 : is sudo user with most of the access
- user2 : is also sudo user with less access
- user3 : is just another user with no sudo access

Im trying to give access to partitions 1 and 2 to user1, user2 and user3 .
The owner of the partition is root.
the partitions are mounted at

```
/media/user2/1
/media/user2/2
```

Note : I tried to mount the partition using

```
sudo mkdir /media/IntHDD170
sudo mkdir /media/IntHDD171
```

Which created the directory to mount the partitions.

- (I dont know this worked or not)

Step 1:

- Used nautilus as root.
- if nautilus is not installed:
      sudo apt-get install nautilus
- Before running nautilus make sure the partition or hard disk is mounted.
- Run nautilus as root with

  ```
  sudo nautilus
  ```
- Your partition or hard disk should appear on the left.

  Right click on it -> select "Properties"

  In the new window that appears, select the "Permissions" tab.
- Kept the owner as "root" and group as "user1" with read and write access for both owner and group.

From here you can change the owner if you need to, as well as the permission for a certain user, root, or others.

Note: The user1 ,user2 and user3 did not get access to the partitions yet

Step 2: Added User2 and user3 to group "user1".

```
usermod -aG user1 user2
usermod -aG user1 user3
```

Step 3:

Did

```
chmod -R 777 /media/user2/1
chmod -R 777 /media/user2/2
```

- opened

  ```
  sudo nano /etc/fstab
  ```
- Went to the last line entered:

  ```
  LABEL=/dev/sda3  /media/$USER/1  auto  nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
  LABEL=/dev/sda4  /media/$USER/2  auto  nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
  ```
- Saved and Exited

  Note: Now i am able to read and write files to the partitions 1 and 2.
- Only issue is, if i have logged into user1 , then try to access partition 1 from user2 , it is not accessible.

I do a reboot:

```
 sudo reboot
```

And access partition 1 from user2.

I don't know if this is the right way to do it. Just combined many responses and did. Somehow its working.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case!

I had this problem in a dual boot (Mint + W10) when windows didn't close down properly. I tried all the combinations to get `rw` permissions. Finally,

```
sudo mount -a
```

let me know the problem.

Going back to windows and turning off the pc did the job. Rights where restored! The fstab entries are written using ntfs-config.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dualbooting windows and Ubuntu then there is an issue of improper dismount of hard-disks by windows. I observed this when I shut down from windows and switch to Ubuntu, I lose my write access to the disks even though I have Read and Write enabled. So, either you can turn off a feature of fast booting windows in the Power Options of Windows or you can Hibernate the windows and then switch to Ubuntu. This solved it for me.
:-)

Answer (score 0):

These posts were very helpful fixing an old HDD for backup. Don’t format on Windows, use Ubuntu GPARTED, Previously I had formatted an old external HDD on Windows 7 as FAT but Ubuntu 20.04 ‘backup’ said it had no permissions to write, ‘backup fails’.  ROOT is the owner and ‘Disks’ would not let me change owners to ‘me’ or change permissions .   Solution: The HD was auto mounted to /dev and using ‘Disks’ I changed the mounting folder to /media/myname and the permissions automatically changed to ‘Me’ and then Ubuntu ‘backup’ executed fine.

This actually took about 6 hours to study and resolve.