# updating 14.04 to newer

Tags: 14.04, boot, system-installation, upgrade

I had a stable Ubuntu 14.04.
It was automatically suggested to update the newer version.
I started it, then after 1 hour it stopped, unfortonutly I don't remember the fail message, but it was in the Terminal and at the end it was an OK
I pressed the power button once, shortly (It was a a huge huge mistake)
The computer swictched off.
I tried to switch it on, but after booting it has a black screen and nothning on it. I waited for 5 minutes. nothing happened.
I pressed the power button shortly, once and it was written in a linux way font letters: Plymouth-poweroff .service
[ OK ] started show plymouth power off scree...
ok      stopped cups scheduler
.

.
.
.
.
.
I am sad about my files on my computer. I haven't got a safety copy. Can anybody help me?

Thank you!

Paul

Comment: When you say "written in a Linux way", you mean "written in a monospace font", right?

Comment: You can keep booting using a Live USB to backup your data. Then, if no solution is asnwered, you can re install Ubuntu from the latest version if you want. I recommend to use a fresh install from a LTS version (16.04). Best regards.

Comment: I don t have permission to copy the files from the hard drive The folder “100D3200” cannot be handled because you do not have permissions to read it.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly suggest making a bootable USB drive with this tool:

http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/
Then, upon boot, select "Repair Broken System". If this doesn't work, don't fret.

Reboot, select "Try Ubuntu without installing", and then you can access your hard drive (and files) in order to make copies before potentially doing a fresh install.

Comment: I don t have permission to copy the files from the hard drive                  "The folder “100D3200” cannot be handled because you do not have permissions to read it"

Comment: Have you tried altering the permissions using chmod (as referenced here)?
http://askubuntu.com/a/90356