# Unable to delete any file or folder in other partition of my laptop hard drive,using ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, partitioning, delete

In my laptop i had windows 10 installed in one of the partition and other partition had all my files. recently i installed ubuntu 18.04 by deleting my windows 10 partition. Everthing is working fine but when i access the other partition of my hard drive, i cant delete any file or folder in there. I am not even getting the option of 'delete' of 'move to trash'... help

output of lsblk -f

```
NAME   FSTYPE  LABEL UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
loop0  squashf                                            /snap/gnome-system-mon
loop1  squashf                                            /snap/core/5328
loop2  squashf                                            /snap/communitheme/848
loop3  squashf                                            /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/
loop4  squashf                                            /snap/core/4206
loop5  squashf                                            /snap/gnome-logs/23
loop6  squashf                                            /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/
loop7  squashf                                            /snap/gnome-calculator
loop8  squashf                                            /snap/gnome-characters
loop9  squashf                                            /snap/gnome-calculator
loop10 squashf                                            /snap/gtk-common-theme
loop11 squashf                                            /snap/gnome-characters
loop12 squashf                                            /snap/core/5145
loop13 squashf                                            /snap/gnome-system-mon
loop14 squashf                                            /snap/gnome-system-mon
loop15 squashf                                            /snap/gnome-logs/40
loop16 squashf                                            /snap/gnome-calculator
loop17 squashf                                            /snap/gnome-characters
loop18 squashf                                            /snap/gnome-logs/37
sda                                                       
├─sda1 ext4          914e2ad9-937d-4dd9-bac9-fec73bd527ce /
└─sda4 ntfs          A6A254BBA2549223                     /media/waqar/A6A254BBA
sr0
```

i am also unable to empty the trash

Comment: Can we see `lsblk -f` add to your question!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set read/write permissions my hard drives?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90339/how-do-i-set-read-write-permissions-my-hard-drives)

Comment: is sda4 the partition you are trying to access?

Comment: yes, im trying to delete items from sda4

Comment: Are you sure you have write permissions?

Comment: is there any particular way to know about the permissions? when i right click in folder>properties>permissions , it says 'create and delete files'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i couldnt solve the problem with any online guide or answers with similar problems. i reinstalled the ubuntu but still the same problem was there. Then i installed windows 10 by deleting ubuntu partition, logged in with windows 10, accessed my other partition and confirmed that cut,copy paste and delete is working. This time i turned off fast boot, shutdown the system and installed ubuntu by deleting the windows 10 partition. Finally the problem is solved. It was a really frustrating experience.