# How can I copy files to my hdd?

Tags: permissions

I installed ubuntu on new SSD, and formatted my old HDD with partition manager, now I can't copy files to the HDD, I got error message, permission denied.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set read/write permissions my hard drives?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90339/how-do-i-set-read-write-permissions-my-hard-drives) - Ignore the part about NTFS in that question, instead, pay attention to the part about the 500GB ext4 drive in that question. Or, if you don't want to, doing `sudo cp` instead of just `cp` would also give you the required permissions.