# Can't write to flash drive unless root

Tags: partitioning, usb, gparted

I formatted my flash drive with GParted and gave it a 32GB FAT32 filesystem. Now, I can only write to it as root! I have tried running the command `sudo chown $USER:$USER -R /media/usb0/`, but I get an Operation not permitted error, which is weird because I ran that command as root. `ls -la /media/usb0/` gives

```
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 16384 Dec 31  1969 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root  4096 Nov  8 08:22 ..
```

sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb1 gives Disk /dev/sdb1: 29.8 GiB, 32004636672 bytes, 62509056 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0009e87d

Device      Boot      Start        End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1p1 ?    3223366752 3470046675 246679924 117.6G f4 SpeedStor
/dev/sdb1p2 ?     378192737  710426324 332233588 158.4G 10 OPUS
/dev/sdb1p3 ?     225603442  225603451        10     5K 74 unknown

Partition table entries are not in disk order.

cat /etc/fstab gives
/etc/fstab: static file system information.
Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a

## device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices

## that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).

#

## / was on /dev/sda1 during installation

UUID=f4b26011-2e69-4f2f-94c5-151e750d615d /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1

## swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation

UUID=4dfce2fd-fad5-4aaa-bebe-bc8500b6f3e6 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/sr0        /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto     0       0
/dev/sr1        /media/cdrom1   udf,iso9660 user,noauto     0       0
/dev/sdb1       /media/usb0     auto    rw,user,noauto  0       0

Comment: I have also tried deleting /media/usb0 (the mount point) and rebooting, but it just creates it again with the same root ownership.

Comment: Can I just repartition the whole thing without having to be root?

Comment: What does `ls -la /media/usb0/` say?

Comment: Check the following link especially the adjustments for FAT16/32 FS.. http://askubuntu.com/a/14872/216503

Comment: @KarlRichter ls -la /media/usb0/ says: total 20
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 16384 Dec 31  1969 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root  4096 Nov  8 08:22 ..

Comment: @heemayl I tried that but I got mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

Comment: Don't comment, edit! The output of `ls` shows that the `chown` command isn't successful. Run it again and check again (and document in the question that you did so).

Comment: I don't have any files on it. Can I just make a new partition table and reformat the whole thing? I tried making a new FAT32 partition with Windows, but that didn't help.

Comment: I ran Thunar as root to try to change the owner. Whenever I changed the owner from root to my name, it would undo itself after a second. Reformatting the whole thing is probably easier.

Comment: Please execute `groups` in a terminal and paste the output.

Comment: @PJSingh groups gives: john cdrom floppy sudo audio dip video plugdev netdev scanner lpadmin vboxusers. P.S. john is my username on my machine.

Comment: I thought you might be missing plugdev, which is required to access removable devices, but you have that.

Comment: Please state the Ubuntu version you are using, and how you have formatted/partitioned the USB (`sudo fdisk -l /dev/yourdevicehere`), and the result of `mount` when the disk is mounted. Add all of this to your question. I suspect you did not partition the stick; the automatic mounting works only if you have partitions, even if it's just one spawning all the device (and it's the best thing for compatibility with other OS, too)

Comment: It's mounted on `/media/usb0`, that's suspicious. What's in your `/etc/fstab`? There might be a line there mounting it to `/media/usb0` and giving root the ownership.

Comment: I'm not using Ubuntu. I'm using Debian Jessie.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo chown myusername /media` to see if that helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize I made this question, but I thought I would post my solution. I just opened up /etc/fstab, deleted the line about my flash drive, plugged it in, and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB#Interfering_services):

```
Interfering services

It might happen, that two services/programs responsible for automounting might interfere and 
thereby prevent a successful automount and permission setting. Example: Activating the Automount
function of Nautilus while using pmount will result read only permissions for normal users. 
Either disable Nautilus' Automount function or deinstall pmount.
```

If you have [package pmount](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/utils/pmount) installed try removing it.

Comment: I don't have pmount installed.

Comment: Although you were not the one who solved my problem (I solved it myself), I have decided to give you the bounty because I thought removing pmount would be a great solution for others that are having this problem. I also don't like seeing a bounty go to waste because I can't give it to myself or take it back.