# How can I load Steam Games on a usb drive simply? (novice user on crouton linux)

Tags: usb-drive, steam, crouton

I am a new ubuntu user and have been using ubuntu trusty tahr with crouton on my acer c11 chromebook.  I can only download Steam games directly to my hard drive (which is not too big) and cannot find anywhere with *simple* tutorials on how to load steam games onto a usb on crouton.  Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 4):

First mount your flash drive with read/write/execute privileges.

[How to auto mount a flash drive with root and read/write/execute privileges](https://askubuntu.com/a/14872/462639)

Then create an empty folder on your flash drive.

Open Steam settings, click on Steam and then click on Settings.

[image]

1. Steam -> Settings -> Downloads
2. Click on <kbd>Steam Library Folders</kbd>

[image]

3.Click on <kbd>Add Library Folder</kbd>
[image]

Find where your flash drive is mounted and locate and select the empty folder you created. Then click on <kbd>Select</kbd>

[image]

Now you will be able to install games to your USB device. If you want your new library folder to be default just right click on it and make it default.

[image]

Just remember to select your new library folder when installing games.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

as far as I now, by default everything related to steam is installed in  `/home/USER/.steam`.

If your USB drive is mounted with execute permission, you can go to steam's settings `menu -> downloads -> content libraries` and add a new content library on your USB drive.

But I don't see the benefit since the USB drives are slow...for simple arcade games they should be enough though

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about this Crouton business, but I store my steam games on a separate drive off my OS SSD.

1. Have Steam installed.
2. Go your games Library. You have no games installed. Mount your external drive.
3. Select a game and Install game.
4. In the drop down list, choose
   Install under /media/username/your-external-drive/Steam
5. This will create a Steam apps folder on your external drive which stores all your games.

One caveat that I have is that my Steam drive does not automatically mount during computer bootup, so I will have to manually mount it, make Steam to "install" it under the same pathname, then Steam will detect all my games.